# CakePHP 3: Undefined Function imagecreatetruecolor

Tags: php, image, cakephp, php-gd

Trying to call a function, but I'm getting an error, the function is really long so here are the important bits.

Avatar.php

```
namespace App\Utility

class Avatar {
     const spriteZ = 128;
     public static function generateAvatar($hash, $size, $path) {
         // .. code happened before this part, it all worked fine
         $avatar = imagecreatetruecolor(self::spriteZ*3, self::spriteZ*3);

     }
}
```

The User Controller:

```
use App\Utility\Avatar;

// ...further down in the code
Avatar::generateAvatar("abcde", 200, "/data/images/avatar.png");
```

The error I get is `Call to undefined function App\Utility\imagecreatetruecolor()`. When I make the function call `\imagecreatetruecolor(self::spriteZ*3, self::spriteZ*3)` I get an error of `Call to undefined function imagecreatetruecolor()` which seems like the more correct error to have...

I do have `php-gd` installed, and I am able to use this file as a standalone file (though I didn't have the namespace part).

Comment: Shooting in the dark I'd say wherever you test the CakePHP app, GD isn't installed/enabled, ie you're probably testing the standalone file with a different PHP installation/confguration.

Comment: They're on the same machine and *should* be using the same php. I'll have to try a phpinfo tomorrow to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Start of changes:

1.Go to installed path `php` and find `php.ini` file,example `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` or everywhere in your computer

2.Open `php.ini` file

> Notice! You must remove many `;` sign,Follow me!

3.Find and change

```
;extension=gd
```

To

```
extension=gd
```

4.Find and change

```
;gd.jpeg_ignore_warning = 1
```

To

```
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning = 1
```

5.Save changes in `php.ini` file

6.Reset Xamp  Apachi or anything you use

7.Reset your computer